# UCanAccess 4.0.2 uppercase column names cannot be found

Tags: java, ucanaccess

In my java program, I want to query some columns in * .mdb using UCanAccess. However, some characters seem wrong because it converts all column names to upper case. For example, on one platform, column name `egitim` becomes `ÈGITIM` in capital letters, while in another it becomes an `ÈGİTİM`. I want my program to be platform independent. 
However, if I write `egitim` in my query, It is working correctly on the first platform and I am getting error on the second. If I write `EGİTİM` this time it does not work on the first platform. Is there a way to set charset of UCanAccess programmatically?

You can see the code below:

```
Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(JAtama.url);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select distinct egitim from dersler");
```

last line gives `net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 user lacks privilege or object not found: EGITIM` exception.

Both platforms are macOS Sierra. But one of them is Turkish and the other one is English. (In Turkish Language capital letter i is İ.

Comment: Please show your code, so that people can replicate the issue. Can you also specify the platforms you're using?

Comment: I was able to recreate this issue with UCanAccess 4.0.2 and have reported it to the UCanAccess development team.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue with UCanAccess 4.0.2 and earlier. The required fix has been merged into the master branch and will be included in the next release of UCanAccess.